# Why to use Fast CGI for an nginx webserver (with lua) and what to set up

Tags: nginx, lua, fastcgi

### Question

Having read a lot of online posts I understand `Fast CGI` as a way of making a web server better at dealing with a large number of web requests whilst also proxying the server.

- Have I understood the reasons for `Fast CGI` correctly or has something
  gone over my head with this, as I feel like my understanding is somewhat 'basic'?
- Is it just a case of me 'turning' Fast
  CGI on, on the web server or are there some recommended modules that
  should be used similar to `nginx` where you can set up ip blocking?

### Context

I wanted to set up a web server where I could store files and allow friends access to them. Mostly as a 'something to do' project to give me some drive to learn some more advanced programming.

As this is my first time working with anything that hasn't been writing Bash or some basic Python scripts, I decided to start off with seeing if I could achieve something similar within a `Google VM`, rather than forking out for a whole PC (as the learning curve feels rather intimidating).

Researching online I saw recommendations for using `nginx` to 'web-enable' the server and using `Fast CGI` and `Lua` for dealing with web requests.

I was able to get `nginx` running and was able to access my server via a webpage. I also figured out assigning credentials and IP blocking using the [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/), however I found `Fast CGI` a bit of a stumbling block as I don't quite understand what I am using it for or what needs to be set up.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what FastCGI is. It is a protocol that is used to communicate with a backend service, such as a PHP FPM, which is used to execute PHP scripts because Nginx does not know how to.

Comment: @RichardSmith So FastCGI is more a translator that allows you to run scripts on a webserver where they otherwise couldn't?

Comment: No. It's a protocol like `http` used to communicate between Nginx and some other system. The other system runs the scripts.

Comment: @RichardSmith ok that makes a little more sense. So in my instance the 'other system' scripts would be `lua`?

Comment: I don’t use lua, but I believe it’s a language extension, so it’s unrelated to FastCGI.

Comment: Nginx (and other web servers) have multiple ways to communicate with your application. FastCGI is one option and there are multiple implementations like https://github.com/cramey/lua-fastcgi, but there is more effective way to use nginx lua module: https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module